# Проблема с paramiko в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, powershell, subprocess, paramiko

Мне нужно подключаться к серверу по ssh принимать его команды и отправлять ему результат.
Код для подключения к серверу:

```
import paramiko
import subprocess

def ssh_command(ip, port, user, passwd, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip, port=port, username=user, password=passwd)
    client.invoke_shell()

    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        ssh_session.send(command)
    print(ssh_session.recv(1024).decode())

    while True:
        command = ssh_session.recv(1024) 
        cmd = command.decode()
        cmd_output = subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        ssh_session.send(cmd_output.stdout or 'None')
```

Но проблема в том что каждая команда не сохраняет свое состояние так как новая команда это новый процесс. И вот я решил это так:

```
import subprocess
import threading

ps = subprocess.Popen(
    ['powershell'],
    encoding='866',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True,
)

def read_output():
    while True:
        line = ps.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line, end='')

output_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_output)
output_thread.start()

while True:
    command = input('введите команду: ')
    ps.stdin.write(command + '\n')
    ps.stdin.flush()
```

Как теперь соединить два кода в один. В первом коде у нас вечный цикл так как мы проверяем есть ли новые команды от сервера и выполняем его и отправляем через `ssh_session.send(cmd_output.stdout or 'None')` а во втором коде мы используем потоки тоже в цикле вечном что бы принимать команды и выполнять их и выдавать результат. Как теперь быть?